# Grails 4 - Gradle 'assemble' task not generating .war.original archive

Tags: gradle, grails, build.gradle, grails-4

I just upgraded my Grails web-app from version 3.2 to 4.0.

I have a `provided` dependency in `build.gradle` (fairly common configuration):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    ...
}
```

I’ve just noticed that by executing Gradle `assemble` task I don’t get the `myApp.war.original` archive anymore (which used to be build without all provided libs), but only the one including provided dependencies.

Am I missing something here? I'd really like to spare those ~4MB of jars in `lib-provided` folder.
Thanks in advance!

---

***Update 1***

Following @ck1's advice i changed `provided` dependency to `providedCompile`, but the result is the same.
Though I already use the `war` plugin, I noticed that the sequence of tasks initiated by `assemble` task is:

```
> Task :assetCompile
Finished Precompiling Assets
> Task :compileJava
> Task :compileGroovy
> Task :buildProperties
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileWebappGroovyPages NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileGroovyPages
> Task :compileGsonViews
> Task :findMainClass
> Task :bootWar
> Task :war SKIPPED
> Task :assemble
```

So the `war` task is skipped in favor of the new `bootWar` task (not available in Gradle 3, used by Grails 3).
Any way to force it? Or is it something the plugin should already support?

---

***Update 2***

After some research, I added to `build.gradle`

```
war {
    enabled = true
}
```

and was able to get the `war` task to execute:

```
> Task :assetCompile
Finished Precompiling Assets
> Task :compileJava
> Task :compileGroovy
> Task :buildProperties
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileWebappGroovyPages NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileGroovyPages
> Task :compileGsonViews
> Task :findMainClass
> Task :bootWar
> Task :war           // not skipped
> Task :assemble
```

I basically got to where I wanted to, i.e. get a .war archive without all the provided dependencies; differently from before though, not a pair of .war archives (`myApp.war` and `myApp.war.original`) but a single one named `myApp.war` not including the unneeded stuff.

But I'm still pretty much confused, as
[Spring Boot's Gradle plugin documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/05/spring-boot-s-new-gradle-plugin#building-executable-jars-and-wars) states `bootWar` is an extension of `war`.

> The bootRepackage task has been replaced with bootJar and bootWar tasks for building executable jars and wars respectively. Both tasks extend their equivalent standard Gradle jar or war task, giving you access to all of the usual configuration options and behaviour.

But then [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#building-executable-jars-and-wars) states `war` task is expected to be skipped:

> The bootRepackage task has been replaced with bootJar and bootWar tasks for building executable jars and wars respectively. The jar and war tasks are no longer involved.

So again, what am I missing out?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `provided` with either the `providedCompile` or `providedRuntime` dependency configuration from the `war` plugin.

> These two configurations have the same scope as the respective compile
>   and runtime configurations, except that they are not added to the WAR
>   archive.

**Reference:**

https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/war_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I made a few tests, explained above in an edit to my question.